# Foundation6: Expanding image in nested column

Tags: image, zurb-foundation

I want to expand the image so that image is 100% width with the browser window with no gutter. It seems adding  row expanded to the image does not do the job. Also I need to figure this out by only editing the css.

```css
.wideimage{
  min-width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row small-collapse">
  <div class="medium-11 medium-centered column">
    <p class="xlarge-8 xlarge-offset-2 ">m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id e</p>
    <div class="degutter wideimage"><img src="http://placehold.it/2400x500"></div>
    <p class="xlarge-8 xlarge-offset-2 ">m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id e</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/835/

Answer (score 0):

This works. I know it's a pain because you have to do the two rows, with the full width div between. But there are no gutter edges. Like so:

```css
.wideimage{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row small-collapse">
  <div class="medium-11 medium-centered column">

    <p class="xlarge-8 xlarge-offset-2 ">m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id e</p>
    
   </div>
</div>

    <div class="degutter wideimage"><img src="http://placehold.it/2400x500"></div>

    <div class="row small-collapse">
  <div class="medium-11 medium-centered column">

    <p class="xlarge-8 xlarge-offset-2 ">m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id e</p>
    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for an solution that doesn't involve editing the html. I am only can edit css.